# Is this kind of activity allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

I found a question which was asked in two sites

> https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4823/are-you-a-geek-or-nerd
>
> https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17779/are-you-a-geek-or-nerd

Need your thoughts on this. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably a good thing to decide.

Personally, I'd vote **yes**:

- It would be very difficult to enforce it if we decided to say that that was unacceptable.
- You're likely to get different answers from different communities (as in that example)
- If it's appropriate for both communities, I can't think of a compelling reason why not.

Comment: IMHO, when it's pertinent, yes. This specific case, no.