# How are questions moved or duplicated between PE and SO?

Tags: discussion, migration

I recently linked my SO account here to PE, and asked a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18838/haskell-and-lisp-vs-haskell-or-lisp). A got some decent answers, but I realized that the question is specific enough to ask on SO and possibly get more interest/views/response.

What should I do in this case? Is it considered bad form to duplicate a question across sites? I'm not trying to game the rep system, I just want my question to get good exposure. Is there a way of migrating the question that doesn't require moderator assistance? Should I just leave the question here on PE?

Comment: I suppose it's a little ironic that after eight hours this question has only been viewed four times.

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/irony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding "Bad form" check [Is this kind of activity allowed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/521/is-this-kind-of-activity-allowed) apparently it has the go ahead from one mod and a word of warning from another (which should not be taken lightly, if you have any doubts as to whether something you post is off topic, he will see to it that it is closed).

I find myself asking questions on programmers.SE that could probably get much better answers from the larger user base on stackoverflow.  The one good thing about this site is that almost nothing slips through the cracks (for better or worse).

I kinda don't think there can be crossposted stuff between SO and here though, there is too much of a disconnect now between "Opinion Answering" on this site and "Just the facts, dude" on SO. You may be able to crosspost a pronunciation question between the English usage site and this one or a snack suggestion between "Seasoned Advice" and this site.  But in each of those cases, the post on this site is probably going to be closed (at least once).

Oh, and I don't think the "migration paths" open up till the site is out of beta (looks like that'll be soon)

Comment: Beta lasts no less than 90 days. So we've got around 30 days to go (as of this writing).

Comment: Eh? We're on 74 days at the moment. Unless someone has rewritten the laws of mathematics, that's sixteen, not thirty? :S

Comment: I'd agree that most questions aren't appropriate for both sites.